# Execute Function from Element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was wondering how to do something like this:

```
function fullScreen() {
    parent.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

For example:

```
document.documentElement.fullScreen();
```

Or

```
myVideo.fullScreen();
```

How could this be done?

Comment: So you want to call a function instead of having setHTML?

Comment: there is no function called `setHTML`... `document.getElementById("myItem").innerHTML = "<p>Hi!</p>";`